# How to spy on an object function returned from a mock in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs

In my app I have something similar to this to `signOutUser` a user.

```js
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
export function signOutUser(): Promise<void> {
  return getAuth(firebaseApp).signOut();
}
```

And I want to make sure that the `signOut` function of firebase is called.

But I can't figure how to mock and spy on the sign out function that is on the auth object.

One attempt I've done...

I'm mocking these functions from `firebase/auth` like so...

```js
const mockSignOut = jest.fn();
jest.mock("firebase/auth", () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    getAuth: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        signOut: mockSignOut,
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

I get `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockSignOut' before initialization` .

If I change it to `var` I get `TypeError: signOut is not a function`

The documentation I think this is kind of close to what I want? But it doesn't explain how you would mock a mocked value that I understand at least https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock

How can I spy on this `signOut` function from the object that `getAuth()` returns and is also mocked?

Answer (score 3):

Jest will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module (before any imports). That means `jest.mock` will be called before the variable is declared. That's why you got the error.

You don't need to provide the mock factory function for `jest.mock` in your case. Just let the jest create mock for `firebase/auth` automatically. That means functions exported(`getAuth`) from the `firebase/auth` module will be mocked.

Then, you should provide a mock implementation for the `getAuth` function.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({});

export function signOutUser(): Promise<void> {
  return getAuth(firebaseApp).signOut();
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { Auth, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { signOutUser } from './';

jest.mock('firebase/auth');

describe('70646844', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const mAuth = ({
      signOut: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown) as Auth;
    (getAuth as jest.MockedFunction<typeof getAuth>).mockReturnValue(mAuth);

    await signOutUser();
    expect(getAuth).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(getAuth().signOut).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    // Better
    // expect(mAuth.signOut).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70646844/index.test.ts (10.306 s)
  70646844
    ✓ should pass (2 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.512 s, estimated 12 s
```